# Unity Android App is not compatible with debugger device after publishing it on Play Store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I created an augmented reallity app using Unity and ARCore Foundation library, I used my Samsung A23 smartphone in order to test and debug it; after everything was working as expected, I published it on play store and after deployment was approved, I found out it is not compatible with my phone. Am I missing something?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Anarvista.anARVistAPP&hl=es

Google Play Store requires the app to set Target API Level to 31 which matches with my cellphone, minimun API Level is set to 28 (Android 9.0 Pie)

This is manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="com.google.ar.core.depth" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="jp.fantom1x.plugin.android.fantomPlugin.FullPluginOnUnityPlayerActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:exported="true"
              android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

[Unity Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK9Wl.png)

I am expecting this app being available and compatible with my Samsung A23 cellphone since I used it for debugging this app before publishing it.

Comment: Try using Unity's Logcat. Set filters accordingly and you should your logs as well as system generated errors.

Comment: The incompatibility error is displayed in Google Play Store, by debugging the app directly in my phone I am not getting any error message